# Is there any method to multiply two boost::multiprecision::cpp_int numbers?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have two `cpp_int` numbers say `a` and `b`.I want to find `a*b`. I could not find a method in the library for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types have overloaded operators. You can just multiply them by `operator*`. Example:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using Int = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

Int a("23948723482739842234234234");
Int b(42);

Int c = a*b;
```